# "Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'managementapp.medicament' doesn't exist"

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm working in simple CRUD application using react, node and express.. so i connected to my mysql data base "managementapp" and i tried to insert information in my db, but im always getting the error "table doesn't exist while i tested locally and it works properly in mysql wrokbensh and im so sure that im spelling the name of my table correctly. so this the code of App.js for react :

```
function App() {
  const [name,setName]=useState("");
  const [description,setDescription]=useState("");
  const [number,setNumbre]=useState(0);

  const addMedicament = () => {
    console.log(name);
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/create",
    {name:name,
    description:description,
    number:number,
  }).then(()=>{
    console.log("succes");
  });
  };
```

and this my index.js for backend part

```
const db=mysql.createConnection({
    user:"root",
    host:"localhost",
    password:"",
    database:"managementapp",
    

});


app.post("/create", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const name=req.body.name;
    const description=req.body.description;
    const number=req.body.number;

    db.query(
    "insert into medicament (name,description,number) VALUES (?,?,?);",
    [name,description,number],
    (err,result) =>{
         if (err) 
         { console.log(err); 
        }
        else { res.send("Values inserted !! "); 
    }
    }
    );
});
```

so im always getting this error

```
{ name: 'erty', description: 'rtyuk', number: '86' }
Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'managementapp.medicament' doesn't exist
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\Chahine\Management\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)   
    at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\Chahine\Management\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:79:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\Chahine\Management\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (C:\Users\Chahine\Management\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\Chahine\Management\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\Chahine\Management\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Chahine\Management\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Chahine\Management\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\Chahine\Management\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (C:\Users\Chahine\Management\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)
    at C:\Users\Chahine\Management\server\index.js:25:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Chahine\Management\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Chahine\Management\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Chahine\Management\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Chahine\Management\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Chahine\Management\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Chahine\Management\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:341:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Chahine\Management\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10) 

{
  code: 'ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE',
  errno: 1146,
  sqlMessage: "Table 'managementapp.medicament' doesn't exist",
  sqlState: '42S02',
  index: 0,
  sql: "insert into medicament (name,description,number) VALUES ('erty','rtyuk','86');"
}
```

Comment: that usually asign that you are connected to another server, that hasn't the table jet.

Comment: @nbk if im connected to another server ,it will give that the dataBase doesn't exist withe the error "Unknown database" .. but he said that the table doesn't exist.. it means it find the database but not the table inside it

Comment: the server is in such matters always right,  maybe you have a typo.. make a  mysqldump of your database and check for anomaly

Answer (score 0):

i was searching since last night and i found that the problem was with my mysql installation .. so i uninstalled it and reinstall it then i changed the port from 3306 to another cause it was already in use .. then i had the error about

```
Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol 
   requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
```

so i just get into mysql and run a query saying root is fine using old mysql_native_password method for authentication:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'YourRootPassword';
```

and everything went right. thanks to [Aidin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2321594/aidin?tab=profile)'s explanation.